# Linux Mandriva Beep Sound

Tags: linux

Linux Mandriva 2008 makes a continuous beep sound after installing on Laptop - Dell M2300.
How can I stop the sound?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I got your question wrong and John T already gave the right answer, but I understood you referred to the system beep, the one you were used to get in the old good days when you would keep a key pressed for too long, under MS-DOS. :)

If that is what you were asking. Then you have to disable the module responsible for that in the kernel (don't panic... it's dead easy!).

From terminal, as root user (or by doing sudo):

```
modprobe -r pcspkr snd_pcsp
```

If that solves your problem, than you can permanently tell the kernel not to load those modules anymore and you can adde them to the file

```
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist
```

Hope this helps!